# Cannot update credit card using session

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to update a `credit-card` using the `StripeCheckout`, I saw that another user has asked a similar thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866338/edit-a-credit-card-using-stripe-checkout-js).

The problem's that I'm not able to replicate the session object without passing any amount, I did:

```
const domainURL = process.env.APP_DOMAIN;

let opts = {
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    mode: 'setup',
    success_url: `${domainURL}/pay/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/pay/cancel`
};

// Make session
let session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(opts);

let url = `${domainURL}/pay/checkout-session?sessionId=${session.id}`;
return url;
```

the code above generate the url for `Stripe` session, and the following window is opened:

[image]

so this seems to works apparently, but when I save the card clicking on "Salva carta" I get:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Stripe: Argument "id" must be a string, but got: null (on API request to `GET /customers/{id}`)

I also tried:

```
 let opts = {
        payment_method_types: ["card"],
        mode: 'setup',
        setup_intent_data: {
            metadata: {
              'customer_id': 'customer id',
            }
        },
        success_url: `${domainURL}/pay/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${domainURL}/pay/cancel`
    };
```

as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/updating)

but same problem

Comment: Is this test live somewhere we can try to replicate the issue with? Seems like Checkout is expecting a customer but none was passed, but it shouldn't require that.

Comment: @w1zeman1p unfortunately I don't have any test environment for you right now. I'm working locally. Do you think that my session options are right? I don't think I should provide the customer as you also said.

Comment: The Checkout implementation there is actually quite old :/

Comment: Have a look at this repo: https://github.com/stripe-samples/developer-office-hours/tree/master/2019-11-21-checkout and this related video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQ5jccnZ2Ow&list=PLy1nL-pvL2M6IYfRCmhOPcyC70zJqFoCs&index=2&t=0s while not in node, you'll get an idea of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this using the following session options:

```
let opts = {
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            mode: 'setup',
            setup_intent_data: {
                metadata: {
                  'customer_id': customerData.stripe_id,
                }
            },
            success_url: `${domainURL}/pay/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
            cancel_url: `${domainURL}/pay/cancel`
        };

        // Create session
        let session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(opts);
```

essentially for update the credit card without charge anything, you must specify the `customer_id` parameter using the `metadata` object which is part of `setup_intent_data`.

An important note about that is the session `mode`, infact the value of this must be `setup`, hope this will help someone.